# mySQL - LOAD DATA INFILE + dar formato a variables

Tags: mysql

Buenos días,

Estoy cargando información desde un fichero txt y, al hacerlo, quiero darle formato a todas las variables de una columna.

En concreto, cargo información DATETIME, que viene como string, y quiero darle el formato correcto para que se guarde bien.

Lo intento hacer con un STR_TO_DATE, pero no carga bien la información.

**Código mySQL completo (variable en la columna 5):**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'in/trazas.txt'
INTO TABLE vn_gmstrazas
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6,@col7)
SET num = @col1, destino = @col2, referencia = @col3, estado = @col4, fecha = STR_TO_DATE(@col5, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), intento = @col6, refweb = @col7;
```

Archivo que se carga (ejemplo de una línea):

```
1;99987984651;;Confirmado;22/12/2017 10:36:00;1;171222W02E2497_1.txt
```

**¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?**

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Intente usar: `STR_TO_DATE('22/12/2017 10:36:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')`, ver [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fjNye5cJiEL7fibUTSpHVz/0).

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que me pasó lo mismo y lo resolví así:
Primero recibo la cadena con **STR_TO_DATE** en formato **dd/mm/aaa**:

```
STR_TO_DATE(@col5, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Y le aplico **DATE_FORMAT** invirtiendo a **aaa-mm-dd**:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(@col5, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d' %H:%i:%s')
```

Por la fecha seguramente ya lo tenés resuelto, pero tal vez a alguien más le sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas Nicolau,

Me he estado informando sobre el tema ya que me sonaba algo de que MySQL no aceptaba dar formato a fechas cuando haces las inserciones, y he verificado que así es.

Si te fijas en el [manual (DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) en los primeros parágrafos explican que `MySQL` sólo trabaja con los formatos **`'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`**. Sabiendo ésto, cualquier formato que intentes poner siempre lo va a cambiar al formato que te he indicado.

La única solución que veo a tu problema sería hacer el proceso inverso, en vez de insertarlas con el formato que deseas las deberías obtener con ése formato.

Comment: Sabiendo esto, lo unico que necesito entonces es poder guardarlo, al menos, en DATETIME en lugar de que se guarde como VARCHAR.
ME EXPLICO: Ahora mismo el archivo es un TXT, y si cargo ese dato en una columna VARCHAR me carga correctamente, pero claro, no deja de ser un string. Sin embargo, si lo cargo en una columna DATETIME no me carga nada, deja el campo vacío, entiendo que porque no tiene el formato correcto.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se guarde correctamente en una columna DATETIME?

Comment: @NicolauRocaRuiz Eso es diferente entonces, en tu pregunta parecía que decías que el campo destino (el de la base de datos) es `DateTime`. Si es `Varchar` entonces tu fallo está en el `STR_TO_DATE(@col5, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')` ya que aquí lo conviertes en `DateTime`, te faltaria una conversión a `Varchar`

Comment: No no, me he debido expresar mal.
Por pasos. Si cargo la información en un campo VARCHAR los datos cargan bien, pero claro, en un campo VARCHAR, que no es lo que quiero.
Ahora, si intento cargar la información en un campo DATETIME, no me carga nada. Entiendo que es porque le viene el dato como una cadena de texto y no es capaz de interpretarlo como DATETIME.
Entonces, lo que yo necesito es leer el archivo txt y, de alguna forma, leer esa cadena de texto y guardarlo en un campo DATETIME.
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: @NicolauRocaRuiz Edita la pregunta para aclarar eso, ya que puede ser crucial para obtener la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

data libreria.tabladesalida;
LENGTH  campo1(char)    $ 8  /*El numero indica el numero de posiciones que va a
ocupar el dato*/
campo2 (num)      3
campo3 (char)   $ 8
campo4 (num)      3;

/*El parentesis  no va, este solo especifica el tipo de dato que es para que vean que formaro lleva*/

Format     campo1(char) $char8  /*El numero indica el numero de posiciones que va a
ocupar el dato*/
campo2 (num)  best3
campo3 (char) $char8
campo4 (num)  best3;

```
    INFILE 'rutadelarchivo'
    DLM=","
    MISSOVER
    DSD 
    FIRSTOBS=2;
INPUT   campo1(char)    : $8.
```

/*El numero indica el numero de posiciones que va a
ocupar el dato*/
campo2 (num)  : ?? 3.
campo3 (char)  : $8.
campo4 (num)   : ?? 3.;
run;